# Binding temporary to const reference in c'tor initializer list

Tags: c++, const-reference, temporaries

Section 12.2.5 in C++03 says "**A temporary bound to a reference member in a
constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits**"
So I tried following program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo
{
  foo()
  {
    cout<<"foo c'tor"<<endl;
  }
  ~foo()
  {
    cout<<"foo d'tor"<<endl;
  }
};

struct bar
{
  const foo &ref;
  bar():ref(foo()) 
  {
    cout<<"bar c'tor"<<endl;
  }

};

int main()
{
  bar obj;
}
```

The output I get is :

```
foo c'tor
foo d'tor
bar c'tor
```

Now according to standard, temporary generated by foo() in c'tor init-list of bar's c'tor will be destroyed after bar's c'tor so `foo d'tor` should be printed after `bar c'tor`
but it's other way around.
Please explain the reason.

Comment: What happens if you reference 'ref' inside the constructor? Maybe the compiler decides that since it isn't actually used it can destroy it earlier.

Comment: VS2008 produces `foo,bar,foo` output where as gcc 4.3.4 produces `foo,foo,bar` output. Interesting...

Comment: g++ bug, report.

Comment: @Tal Pressman : Yes I tried that too : http://www.ideone.com/nm9NA

Comment: just for info: in MS VS warning C4413: 'bar::ref' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits

Comment: Re-running @HappyMittal's code, it looks like this is now fixed: http://ideone.com/zJwC3Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this with MS VS 2010, and it gives me the output also gives warning during compile:

**warning C4413: 'bar::ref' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits**

```
foo c'tor
bar c'tor
foo d'tor
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It seems that MS VS 2010 implements specification correctly. I agree that it is a bug for g++.

EDIT: ref should be initialized in constructor`s initialize list.